# Will upgrade remove the Oracle VM VirtualBox software?

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 22.04

I decide to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS to 22.04.2 LTS,
does upgrading will remove my installed software like for example Oracle VM VirtualBox? I have several virtual machines in, I don’t want to lose them or any of my works inside them.

update added:
When I run "apt update", I got this image:
[image]

Comment: The virtual machines themselves will not be modified if you upgrade your OS. However, depending on *how* you installed VirtualBox, that software may be updated at the same time.

Comment: Assuming you're using the default `virtualbox`, package change in that case will be from `virtualbox | 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1       | focal-updates/multiverse   | source, amd64` to `virtualbox | 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1       | jammy-updates/multiverse   | source, amd64`  As for changes, I'd read changelog for best clues; but via package version change appears minimal (*re-package for new release*)

Comment: Backing up your data (and VMs) before a release-upgrade is a great way to prevent unexpected catastrophes.

Comment: @matigo This means every software I installed from Ubuntu software or official websites will not be removed after the system upgrade? like 'Formatting' did

Comment: @guiverc Are you mean the changes will happen automatically by default after upgrading, the software will be updated itself and I can find my previous virtual machines in it? I got the VirtualBox software from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: @user535733 How could I back up my virtual machines?

Comment: I don't use LTS releases, thus do my *release-upgrade* every 6 months, and I've not lost any of my VMs due to those six monthly *release-upgrades*... I'm using the Ubuntu repository versions of `virtualbox` though, and not 3rd party (the version you got is from Virtualbox thus 3rd party to Ubuntu) so my packages are QA-tested as for *release-upgrades*.  I always backup my files though (VMs are just files that exist on the host machine; when you create the VM you control the filename/location) but I've had no reason to restore any of those backups...